# How I can compare Kolmogorov and Lilieforce tests on plot?

Tags: r

I need to compare two types of tests and show that Kolmogorov test is worse than Lilieforce test.I need to show p-values distribution which will show that Kolmogorov test becomes conservative if parameters unknown and Lilieforce becomes accurate. I tried to get all p-values from kolmogorov test:

```
n = 20
for (i in 1:n){
  x <- rnorm(1000)
  data1<-matrix(x,n,1)
  ks.test(x,pnorm)
  data2<-matrix(ks.test(data1[i,],pnorm,mean(x),sd(x))$p.value,n,1)

  plot(data2,col = "red",lwd = 3,  type ='l')
  curve(punif(x), add = TRUE)
}
```

but as a result I got one single line. Maybe I did smth wrong?

Comment: Have a look at lines()

Comment: @Christoph, smth like that -   lines(data2,col = "red",lwd = 3,  type ='l')?

Right now I got only several lines and that is all :( As I understood I have to get smth like diagonal line which will be similar to (1,0)

Comment: It seems you can delete the first part of the question. Please reduce to a minimal working example.

Comment: every time you call plot, it restarts your device. you have to do a plot(NULL,xlim=c(0,1)); then start the loop..

Answer (score 0):

If someone will be interested in right answer:

```
install.packages("nortest")
library(nortest)
p1 <-c()
p1a <-c()
p2 <-c()
a <- 1
s <- 2
for (i in 1:10000){
  x <- rnorm(100, a, s)
  p1<-c(p1,ks.test(x,pnorm, a, s)$p.value)
  p1a<-c(p1a,ks.test(x,pnorm, mean(x),sd(x))$p.value)
  p2<-c(p2,lillie.test(x)$p.value)
}
distribpt1<-ecdf(p1)
distribpt2<-ecdf(p2)
distribpt1a<-ecdf(p1a)

plot(distribpt1,col = "red",lwd = 3, xlim=c(0, 1))
lines(distribpt2,col = "blue",lwd = 3)
lines(distribpt1a,col = "green",lwd = 3)
lines(c(0,1),c(0,1),lwd=2,cex=1.5)
```

and its result:
[image]